# Add css from a block

Tags: magento, block

I am building a custom magento module and i try to add a custom css file to my block. I wrote :

```
<?php
class Wise_InteractiveSlider_Block_Slider extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
   protected function _prepareLayout()
   {
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addCss('css/mycompany/mymodule/stylesheet.css');
      return parent::_prepareLayout();
   }

 }
```

but it doesn't work, my css file is not loaded, any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Does a link element for your CSS get added to the page when your block is loaded?  It's narrows down the problem area if it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My alternative solution was to add this in my xml layout :

```
<default>
  <reference name="head">
      <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/interactiveslider.css</stylesheet></action>
  </reference>
</default>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

All the CSS & Images are normally available in the "`skin`" folder. It should be:-

```
"skin" folder
   -> Package Name (like "base" or "default")
      -> Theme Name (like "modern" or "mycompany")
         -> "css" folder
            -> "mymodule" folder
               -> "stylesheet.css" file
```

So I suppose that you have been following this above-mentioned basic structure, which is considered as one of the best practices.

Coming back to your question, I suppose that you have mentioned the correct block class in your module's layout file "`layout.xml`". So the above code should be, according to the above folder structure:-

```
<?php
class Wise_InteractiveSlider_Block_Slider extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
   protected function _prepareLayout()
   {
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addCss('css/mymodule/stylesheet.css');
      return parent::_prepareLayout();
   }
}
```

Lastly, please make sure that you have uploaded your CSS file "`stylesheet.css`" in the correct folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used it but it doesn't work in my case. I give my solution in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the _prepareLayout() method if the block is defined in the layout XML. If you 'inline' the block inside a CMS page via the {{block type... method, the layout is already prepared by the time the block is rendered